# $_GET['id'] não retorna valor

Tags: php

Faço uma busca com no mysql, mas, o $_GET['id'], não mostra, apesar de mostrar na barra de endereço : http://localhost/camisetas/index.php?funcao=editar$id=18

```
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id= '". $_GET['id'] ."'");
```

Porque não retorna o número do id assim?

Comment: Cuidado com SQL injection! http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL      ......Você deveria usar MySQLi/PDO e prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AleMoraes, apesar de está pergunta já ter sido respondida há algo errado com seu código não há uma forma natural de um `&` da URL virar um `$` mesmo quando se envia um `<form>` usando o método GET (parametros na URL) ele cóloca altomaticamente o `&` separando as `variaveis`passadas pela URL, outro cenario é você ter construido esta URL com

`$parametros = http_build_query($objeto);`

`http://localhost/camisetas/index.php?id=18&name=bill&sobrenome=gates`

a URL estaria completamente formatada.

Comment: Obrigado @RicardoHenrique, ainda estou começando, valeu pela dica

Comment: Já dei um upvote, na mesma hora

Answer (score 4):

Mude desse: `$id=18`

para esse: `&id=18`

Comment: Puts, valeu man, era isso